# Validar usuario utilizando metodo Session

Tags: javascript, express, login, session, express-session

Me encuentro haciendo un ejercicio sobre Session, y vengo muy muy trabada, intenté de todo para que funcione el ejercicio y me tira error en la consola donde lo estoy haciendo.
La consigna es la siguiente

> En este ejercicio tenemos un controlador y nosotros debemos hacer que
> valide que haya seteada una variable en Session. Si esta variable se
> encuentra, se debe ejecutar el código normalmente, pero si no, se debe
> redireccionar hacia la página de login. Para esto vamos a crear un if
> que consulte si existe el atributo admin dentro de session. Si es así,
> ejecutamos el código normalmente. Este if que agreguemos tiene que
> tener un else en donde hagamos la redirección.

Mi código en base a eso es el siguiente:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({secret: "frase secreta"}));

const admin = (req, res) => {
    if (session.admin){
        admin = {}
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, por que ya no se de qué otra manera puedo plantearlo para que este bien :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente el error sea que estás usando la referencia a la librería para consultar la variable, y no la sesión para consultar la variable... es decir, el if debería ser `if(req.session.admin)`. Si lees la documentación de la librería `express-session` te darás cuenta que lo que hace es poner la sesión en la propiedad `req.session`.

tu código debería quedar así:

```
const admin = (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.admin){
        admin = {}
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvió mucho tu respuesta y explicación <3 @pipe

Comment: Con gusto. Si te sirvió mi respuesta considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, para así, ayudar a la comunidad. Saludos.

Comment: Ya está, amigo! Muchas gracias <3